# Weinre: target not connected

Tags: debugging, cordova, weinre

I've added weinre script to *.html.

Then I click on weinre debug link.

Then I launch app on local webserver in Firefox.

That's what is shown in console:
[image]

Weinre shows "target not connected"

Comment: as far as I know weinre works only with webkit browsers

Comment: Yes, weinre only works with webkit-based browsers; it relies on a lot of webkit-specific css to display the Inspector panes correctly, as that code originates from the WebKit project itself.

For alternatives to weinre, please see the [weinre home page](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre-docs/latest/)

Comment: Spent a day while trying to configure weinre, so may be this will help you, 1.You have to make sure firewall is not the connection, and 2. in my case, i figured out, that weinre does not support **https**, so you have to visit your web app on mobile(target) via **http** and **not https**, hope this helps